# Jquery Autocomplete with multiple arrays as source

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i have a scenario where i need to show Doctors and the doctors which are in the network of user like a social network on search using jquery autocomplete, i have successfully shown the doctors but i am unable to make some way to display data from both arrays in autocomplete categorized so that it shows doctors under doctor heading and the connected doctors under connections heading but i am not getting how to use to array in the autocomplete. Here is my Json returned from server:

```
    {"connections":
    [{"ConnectionID":"8","ConnectionName":"Saima Fayyaz","ImageName":"201304061217391.5x1.5.jpg"}],
    "doctors":
[{"DoctorID":"4","DoctorName":"Imran Saeed Ali","ImageName":"20130516210722ImranSAli.jpg","Type":"Doctor"},
{"DoctorID":"8","DoctorName":"Saima Fayyaz","ImageName":"201304061217391.5x1.5.jpg","Type":"Doctor"},
{"DoctorID":"10","DoctorName":"Sabira  Javaid","ImageName":"20130406123414123.jpg","Type":"Doctor"}]}
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#people").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Search","SearchPathologist")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    flag: "all"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data.doctors);
                    response($.map(data.doctors, function (item) {
                        // alert(item.Type);
                        return {
                            //data: item.doctors
                              id: item.DoctorID,
                              name: item.DoctorName,
                              photo: item.ImageName,

                        }
                    }));

                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {

        }

    })
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

    return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<div style='width:100%; margin:auto; background:white; min-height:20px;'><div style='border-bottom:1px dashed gray;'><div style='float:left;  width:16%; min-height:35px; margin:auto;'><img src='http://olivecliq.com:84/carepoint/doctor_images/"+item.photo+"' width='31px' style='margin-top:4px; margin-left:1px;' /></div><div class='mid_card'><h2> " + item.name + "</h2><h3>Use StrongVPN &amp; have a USA or UK IP address anywhere.</h3></div><div style='float:left;width:10%; min-height:25px; margin:auto;'> <img src='@Url.Content("~/images/arrow.png")' width='25' style='margin-top: 10px;' /></div><div style='clear:both;'></div></div>")
    .appendTo(ul);


});
```

I am really stuck any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this to overcome the problem.

Here is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var drew = false;
    $("#people").on("keyup", function (event) 
    {
        var query = $("#people").val();

        if ($("#people").val().length >= 1) 
        {
            $('div#loaderContainer').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Search","SearchPathologist")',
                dataType: "json",
                data:
                    {
                        term: query,
                        flag: "all"
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                    $.fallr('show', {
        content: '<p>Error occured! May be your session expired.</p>'
                    });
                    },
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    $('div#loaderContainer').hide();
                        //First search
                        if (drew == false) 
                        {
                            //Create list for results
                            $("#people").after("<ul id='res' class='ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' role='listbox' aria-activedescendant='ui-active-menuitem' style='z-index: 10005; display: block; width: 293px;'></ul>");

                            //Prevent redrawing/binding of list
                            drew = true;

                            //Bind click event to list elements in results
                            $("#res").on("click", "li.item", function () 
                            {
                                $("#people").val($(this).text());
                                $("#res").empty();
                            });
                        }
                        //Clear old results
                        else 
                        {
                            $("#res").empty();
                        }



                        $.each(data.doctors, function (i, item) {
                            if(i==0)
                            {
                            $("#res").append("<div id='doctors'></div>")
                            $("#doctors").append("<li style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #499BEA 0%, #207CE5 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); margin-left:2px;text-align:center;color:white;'>Doctors</li>");
                            }
                            $("#doctors").append("<li class='item'><div style='width:100%; margin:auto; background:white; min-height:20px;'><div style='border-bottom:1px dashed gray;'><div style='float:left;  width:16%; min-height:35px; margin:auto;'><img src='http://olivecliq.com/carepoint/doctor_images/"+item.ImageName+"' width='31px' style='margin-top:4px; margin-left:1px;' /></div><div class='mid_card'><h2> " + item.DoctorName + "</h2><h3></h3></div><div style='float:left;width:10%; min-height:25px; margin:auto;'> <img src='@Url.Content("~/images/arrow.png")' width='25' style='margin-top: 10px;' /></div><div style='clear:both;'></div></div></li>");
                        });

                        $.each(data.connections, function (i, item) {
                            if(i==0)
                            {
                            $("#res").append("<div id='connections'></div>")
                            $("#connections").append("<li style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #499BEA 0%, #207CE5 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); margin-left:2px;text-align:center;color:white;'>Connections</li>");
                            }
                            $("#connections").append("<li class='item'><div style='width:100%; margin:auto; background:white; min-height:20px;'><div style='border-bottom:1px dashed gray;'><div style='float:left;  width:16%; min-height:35px; margin:auto;'><img src='http://olivecliq.com/carepoint/doctor_images/"+item.ImageName+"' width='31px' style='margin-top:4px; margin-left:1px;' /></div><div class='mid_card'><h2> " + item.ConnectionName + "</h2><h3></h3></div><div style='float:left;width:10%; min-height:25px; margin:auto;'> <img src='@Url.Content("~/images/arrow.png")' width='25' style='margin-top: 10px;' /></div><div style='clear:both;'></div></div></li>");
                        });


                    if($('button#searchDDL').html() == "Doctors")
                    {
                    $('div#connections').hide();
                    }
                    if($('button#searchDDL').html() == "Connections")
                   {
                   $('div#doctors').hide();
                   }



                }


            });


        }

        else
        {
        $("#res").empty();
        $( "#res" ).remove();
        drew = false;
        }
    });


          $("input#people").focusout(function () {

$( "#res" ).remove();
drew = false;


});
});
</script>
```

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="search_input"><input type="text" id="people" placeholder="Search for specialist doctors and more.." />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="search-button" value="Search" name="search">
        <span><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/search-icon.png")" height="20" /></span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Here is my action:

```
public JsonResult Search(string term, string flag)
        {
            using (OliveCliqService.OliveServiceClient client = new OliveCliqService.OliveServiceClient())
            {
                PathWay.OliveCliqService.SearchResult result = new PathWay.OliveCliqService.SearchResult();

                result = client.Search(Session["userID"].ToString(), term, flag);

                return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Here is my WCF Service method:

```
public SearchResult Search(string PersonID,string term,string flag)
        {
            string cmd;
            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OliveCliq"].ConnectionString;


            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            cmd = @"SELECT DISTINCT d.DoctorID,
d.FirstName,
d.LastName,
d.Image,
r.name,
s.Spaciality_name,
oc.clinic_name,
cb.Location,
rpd.acronym
FROM doctor_members dm
LEFT OUTER JOIN doctors d on dm.member_id = d.doctorid
LEFT OUTER JOIN clinic_doctor_designations cdd on d.doctorid = cdd.doctor_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN rm_pr_designations de on cdd.designation_id = de.designationid
LEFT OUTER JOIN doctor_spcialities ds on d.doctorID = ds.doctorid
LEFT OUTER JOIN spaciality s on ds.spacialityID = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN clinic_doctor_departments dd on dm.member_id = dd.doctor_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN rm_pr_departments r on dd.department_id  = r.departmentid
LEFT OUTER JOIN clinic_doctors cd on dm.member_id = cd.DoctorID
LEFT OUTER JOIN clinic_branches cb on cd.clinic_branch_id = cb.branch_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN clinics oc on cb.clinic_id = oc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN doctor_education dee on dm.member_id = dee.doctorid
LEFT OUTER JOIN rm_pr_degrees rpd on dee.degreeid = rpd.degreeid
where dm.doctor_id  = '" + PersonID + "' And d.FirstName like '" + term + "%' group by d.DoctorID LIMIT 5";

            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);

            SearchResult result = new SearchResult();

            //List<string> listTest = new List<string>();

            List<Doctor> doctorList = new List<Doctor>();

            List<Connection> connectionList = new List<Connection>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                //string test = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TestName"].ToString();

                Connection objConnection = new Connection();

                objConnection.ConnectionID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DoctorID"].ToString();
                objConnection.ConnectionName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LastName"].ToString();
                objConnection.ImageName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Image"].ToString();
                //objConnection.Type = "Connection";
                connectionList.Add(objConnection);
            }

            con.Close();


            cmd = @"SELECT DISTINCT d.DoctorID,
d.FirstName,
d.LastName,
d.Image
FROM doctors d
where (d.FirstName like '"+term+"%') and (d.DoctorID not in ( select dm.member_id FROM doctor_members dm )) LIMIT 5";

            con.Open();

            MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);

            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

            da1.Fill(ds1);



            //List<string> listTest = new List<string>();

           // List<Doctor> doctorList = new List<Doctor>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                //string test = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TestName"].ToString();

                Doctor objDoctor = new Doctor();

                objDoctor.DoctorID = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DoctorID"].ToString();
                objDoctor.DoctorName = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LastName"].ToString();
                objDoctor.ImageName = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Image"].ToString();
                objDoctor.Type = "Doctor";
                doctorList.Add(objDoctor);
            }

            result.connections = connectionList;
            result.doctors = doctorList;


            return result;
        }
```

Here is my SearchResult class:

```
public class SearchResult
    {
        public List<Doctor> doctors { get; set; }
        public List<Connection> connections { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Doctor class:

```
public class Doctor
    {
        public string DoctorID { get; set; }
        public string DoctorName { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my connection class:

```
public class Connection
    {
        public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionName { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
    }
```

I also made a tutorial post on my blog see below link for details:

http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/facebook-and-linkedin-like-searching.html?m=0